# My external style sheet is not affecting my HTML files

Tags: css, html, web

I have made an external style sheet in which I believed would have effected my HTML files when I ran them on notepad++. However, this is not the case. It does not seem to affect it at all. I believe the link is correct, but I do not understand why it isn't working. This is my first website I am creating. If you need any more images, please comment and ask. I am rather clueless at the moment.[image: External css help]

Comment: Where is WebsiteStyles.css located? Is it right next to the WebEnvironment.html file?

Comment: No, it is in a seperate folder. I got told it was good practice to seperate yoour css, html and javascript files away from one another

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS file is in a separate folder. You have to specify this folder.
You have to know it has to be in a subfolder of the folder containing `WebEnvironment.html`.

The most common way is:
`css/WebsiteStyles.css`

Then you have to use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/WebsiteStyles.css" media="screen">
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have the rel wrong. rel needs to be equal to stylesheet, not websiteStyles

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WebsiteStyles.css" media="screen">
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not work either. It was like that originally and it hasn't seemed to change anything

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a working example.

index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Example webpage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="example">
This is an example div
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

style.css file

```
#example {
width: 350px;
height: 350px;
background-color: green;
}
```

index.html and style.css have to be in the same folder for this example!
To learn and understand CSS and HTML I recommend [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)

## edit

Well I didn't read about that you are holding css file in separate folder. href specifies location of the file.